# Handling onclick for button added to another application

Tags: delphi

I am adding a button to another application. It is a third party app where I do not have access to the source code and would like to add some functionality to it.

I added the button as follows

```
var
  oButton : Tbutton;
begin
 oButton := TButton.Create(self);
 oButton.OnClick :=  oButtonClick;  //defined elsewhere
 oButton.caption := 'Button1';
 oButton.ParentWindow := hand; // hand := handle of a toolbar from another app
end;
```

This all works fine, the button gets added to the taskbar of the other app

When I click the button I get an

> ---
>
> xxxxxx
>
> ---
>
> ### Access violation at address 00558183 in module 'xxxxxxxxx.exe'. Read of address 00000278.
>
> ### OK

Why am I getting an access violation, and how can I make the onclick event fire instead?

I get this access violation whether I define the onlick event or not, and it does not execute the onclick event at all.

I added a popupmenu to the button and that works fine. I can right click on the button and I get the menu, and select an item and that works.

edit: After establishing that this is not a good way to go about it. I used the method posted here:

[Create Buttons, Labels, Forms and other objects in ANOTHER Application](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21109145/Create-Buttons-Labels-Forms-and-other-objects-in-ANOTHER-Application.html)

works for what I needed.

Comment: Why would you think you can arbitrarily add controls to a different application and they will magically work?

Comment: This isn't going to work. Ever.

Comment: As I said, the button is added to the other application, and if I add a popup menu to the button, it works. So technically I can use this approach to do what I want, by having the user right click on the button and select an item from the menu. It is not ideal, and would rather have the onclick event work. 
My question is why does the popup menu work but not the onclick.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Why should it work? Cross process UI with some unsuspecting victim process is not expected to work.

Comment: whoever down voted me, can I know why? Just so I don't make the same mistake next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the `TButton` object inside your own process, and attaching its internal `HWND` to a parent `HWND` running in another process.  This will never work.  For one thing, `HWNDs` have thread affinity.  They only operate in the thread that creates them, and only that thread can receive messages for them.  Your button's `HWND` and the parent `HWND` are being created in different threads.  Not a good combination.  Raymond Chen touches on this issue in his blog:

[Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683/)

To *safely* do what you are asking for, you would likely have to inject code into the other process (`CreateRemoteThread()`, etc) to subclass the parent `HWND` itself so you can then create your button `HWND` (not a `TButton` object!) in the same thread as the parent `HWND` and process the button's messages in that same thread, all within the address space of the other process, not in your process.  When the user clicks on the button, it can use an IPC mechanism of your choosing (window message, named pipe, mailslot, etc) to relay the information back to your app as needed.

Comment: Thanks Remy for answering my question.

Comment: I am creating the button in my main app thread, I'm just attaching it to another window. I still want the main thread of the delphi program to handle the onclick event. My goal is just to attach the button to the other app, to have easy access to my Delphi program.

Comment: "*I am creating the button in my main app thread. I'm just attaching it to another window*" - and therein lies the problem. Don't do that, especially when the other app is not designed to cooperate with your app. "*I still want the main thread of the delphi program to handle the onclick event*" - you can't do that directly. You need to hook the other app and delegate the click from the other process to your process. "*My goal is just to attach the button to the other app, to have easy access to my Delphi program.*" - there is nothing *easy* about cross-process UI interactions.